# Angular 15: Getting TypeError: (intermediate value).ngOnDestroy is not a function at ServerStylesHost.ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am getting a `TypeError: (intermediate value).ngOnDestroy is not a function at ServerStylesHost.ngOnDestroy`
when adding ssr support to my angular 15 application.

Application works when served normally, but when served with ssr

```
npm run dev:ssr
```

or `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` throws that error

Anyone already faced this issue ?

Not able to spot the issue

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it work is to comment out the 3 lines of code inside the **ngOnDestroy()** method inside **dist/YOUR_APP_NAME/server/vendor.js** and run again with **npm run serve:ssr**

```
ngOnDestroy() {
// this._styleNodes.forEach(styleNode => styleNode.remove());
// this._styleNodes.clear();
// super.ngOnDestroy();
}
```

The same problem appears while deploying it with SSR, at that time remove the below code from **main.js** file and deploy it.

```
ngOnDestroy(){this._styleNodes.forEach(styleNode => styleNode.remove());this._styleNodes.clear();super.ngOnDestroy();}
```

Comment: Any way to fix it from the code? This is not a fix

Comment: I know but i couldn't find any way to test the SSR so I tried this work around. This is working for us but If you find any other solution please update it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Angular 15 and it was solved when upgrading to Angular 16.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).